# data.frame group_by: latest order date + name

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a `data.frame` with a bunch of sales information i.e. order.date, buyer.name, buyer.email, etc. I'm using the `dplyr` package to do a `group_by` and `summarise` the information, like this:

```
sum = 
  df %>%
  select(order.date, buyer.name, buyer.email, item.type, item.name, item.price, quantity, item.total) %>%
  group_by(buyer.email) %>%
  summarise(total.items = sum(quantity), total.amount = sum(item.total)) %>%
  arrange(desc(total.amount))
```

This gives me a list of emails with `total.items` and `total.amount` per email. What I also want is the latest `order.date` and the last `buyer.name` used for the email. Is there a way to do that with `dplyr`? If not, what's the most efficient way of going about that?

Comment: It is better to show a reproducible example.  I think in the `summarise`, you can also include `order.date=max(order.date), buyer.name=last(buyer.name)` or `last(order.date)` assuming that it is already ordered

Comment: The `last()` function is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.